# With Prism, can I use DependencyInjection by Microsoft rather than using either Prism.Unity or Prism.DryLoc?

Tags: .net, wpf, prism, unity-container

My .NET 6 WPF application uses Prism.Wpf 8.1.97.  I am also using Visual Studio Community 2022 (64bit). I am hesitant to use Prism.Unity because Unity has been deprecated. Because of my experience with the now deprecated Unity, I do not want to use Prism.Unity.  I am also wary of DryLoc considering that in the future it could suffer the same fate.

So, I'd rather switch to Microsoft DependencyInjection if it will give me tools similar to Unity.  Can I use Microsoft DependencyInjection in lieu of Prism.Unity or Prism.DryLoc?

Comment: Unity was originally created by Microsoft.  What makes you think Microsoft.DependencyInjection will be any safer?  I've used DryIoc and Prism with great success.

Comment: I've never used Dryloc, but I have used Unity for years, and I like it a lot.  It just bothers me that it is no longer supported.  As to Microsoft.DependencyInjection being any safer, probably not in the very long run, but I have to hang my hat on something.  I guess it will be Unity for now.

Comment: For what it's worth, Prism is architected so that you can use any DI container you want, so long as it has a suitable feature set.  All you have to do is write a small shim for it, like [this one](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/src/Wpf/Prism.DryIoc.Wpf).  So if a container you are using becomes no longer viable, you have a path forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Prism.Container.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Container.Extensions/). It seems to work, but it's not recommended for production.

Prism relies on named registrations, a feature that the Microsoft container does not have. All in all, Microsoft's DI is a very feature-limited container, compared to Unity or Dry-Ioc, more of a proof of concept meant for application examples.

I'd rather stick with Unity, as it's a mature and very feature-rich container. Even though there won't be new versions in the foreseeable future, it also works just fine.

Your app shouldn't rely too much on a specific container, anyway, and it should only be used in very, very few classes. So you can always later switch to a different container with minimal effort, if need arises.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  I agree that Unity works just fine, but how long until a new version of Prism, or .NET, introduces breaking changes?  It just makes me a little nervous, but I will follow your suggestion and use it.   :-)